# Always display entire tick labels on wcs axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, astropy

I'm reading data in from a FITS file and plotting a velocity field.  I'm using `set_major_formatter('dd:mm')` for the angle on the y-axis, but for every other tick it's only displaying the minutes.  I want the full degrees and minutes to show up for each tick label.

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)
plt.set_cmap('gray')
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=wcs)
im = ax.imshow(mean_vel, vmin=-115, vmax=-102, origin='lower') # plot data

dec = ax.coords[1]
dec.set_major_formatter('dd:mm')
dec.set_ticks([29.5, 30, 30.5, 31, 31.5, 32, 32.5, 33] *u.deg)
dec.set_ticklabel(size=6)
```

[image: Current image]

For example the `00'` on the y-axis should be displayed as `32°00'` instead

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](http://wcsaxes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ticks_labels_grid.html) this behaviour is at least expected.

Comment: I suggest you use the package `aplpy` for plotting fits images. It is very flexible when it comes to edit the figure aesthetic. Regarding your issue, you can specify the [label formatting](http://aplpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/arbitrary_coordinate_systems.html#label-formatting) with zero hassle. Cleaner code = better code

Comment: @VinceP: aplpy may be moving toward becoming deprecated; `wcsaxes` (the approach taken by the OP) is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

As another has said, this behaviour is expected and built in to Astropy via the `TickLabels` class function `simplify_labels` (see [Astropy source](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/master/astropy/visualization/wcsaxes/ticklabels.py)). (It is horrible practice but...) Commenting out the call that the tick label positioner `_set_xy_alignments` makes to `simplify_labels` clears up the issues with over-simplifying the labels.